# downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "summernote" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:2)

Tags: jquery, css, summernote, sanitizer

I'm facing some problems with this summernote font-family, it's being rejected by the sanitizer, and the error are pointing to this css URL:

```
@font-face{font-family:"summernote";font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;src:url("./font/summernote.eot?4c7e83314b68cfa6a0d18a8b4690044b");src:url("./font/summernote.eot?4c7e83314b68cfa6a0d18a8b4690044b#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),url("./font/summernote.woff?4c7e83314b68cfa6a0d18a8b4690044b") format("woff"),url("./font/summernote.ttf?4c7e83314b68cfa6a0d18a8b4690044b") format("truetype")}[class^="note-icon-"]:before,[class*=" note-icon-"]:before
```

specific in the

```
url("./font/summernote.ttf?4c7e83314b68cfa6a0d18a8b4690044b")
```

part.

I've found some Font-awesome solutions, but idk if they fit in my problem, since it's the summernote font-family.

I'm calling it by this code:

```
$('#description').summernote({
            toolbar: [],
            width: null,
            height: null,
            minHeight: 150,
            maxWidth: 400,
            focus: true,
            maxTextLength: 5000,
            disableDragAndDrop: true,
            popover: {
                image: [
                    ['remove', ['removeMedia']],
                ],
});
```